# Why UserNotFound error in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, mongodb

I would like to be able to access `mongodb://admin:password@db:27017/testdb`, but I keep getting

```
Command: ./node_modules/east/bin/east migrate --adapter east-mongo --url mongodb://admin:password@db/testdb
[conn7] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on testdb from client 172.17.2.60 ; UserNotFound Could not find user admin@testdb
```

`db` is the hostname. This is what I have done:

```
mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --httpinterface --rest --master --auth &
mongo admin --eval "db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'password', roles:[{role:'root',db:'admin'}]});"
```

If I do

```
mongo admin -u admin -p password --host db --port 27017
```

then `show dbs` works.

Now I want to access `testdb` which I haven't created yet, but from my understanding databases that doesn't exist are created on the fly?

```
mongo testdb -u admin -p password --host localhost --port 27017
2016-06-08T16:14:02.146+0200 E QUERY    Error: 18 Authentication failed.
```

**Question**

Can anyone see why I can't connect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to authenticate against a database that is non-existent or empty. This is why the authentication fails.

I would

1. log in into MongoDB.
2. execute `use testdb` to switch to *testdb* database
3. execute `db.createuser(...)` with the appropriate options to create a user/password which you can use to authenticate with

Then you should be able to do what you described.